# Set child property sooner than OnBeforePrint

Tags: delphi, fastreport, delphi-10-seattle

I would like to set the `StartNewPage` property of my child band from code based on some data from my database. I am using this to force a pagebreak if it is needed. If I try to modify this property in the `OnBeforePrint` event, it seems to ignore it on the first page of every report, then it starts to work on pages after that. Is there any way to set that property even sooner than `OnBeforePrint`? I am using FastReport 5.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set child band's StartNewPage property when main band (TfrxMasterData for example) is printed